# python: shift column in pandas dataframe conditionally on one column up by one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a pandas dataframe. I want to 'lag' one of my column conditionally on an other columns. Typically below, i want to lag gdp based on y previous "real" value.

Typically first entry will be 0 because we are looking for y = 0.

Second entry will be 2 because we are looking for y = 1

Third entry will be zero because we are looking for y = 3

etc...

```
df = 
      y  gdp  cap
  0   1    2    5
  1   2    3    9
  2   4    7    2
  3   5    4    7
  4   6    7    7

df_lag =
    y  gdp  cap  y_prev gdp_lag
0   1    2    5  0      0
1   2    3    9  1      2
2   4    7    2  3      0
3   5    4    7  4      7
4   6    7    7  5      4
```

Is there any simple way to do that?

Comment: Tell us what you already tried and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did any of the answers work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the `shift` method, you can simply do a lookup. I make `y` the index of a simple series, and use `.loc` to access the values:

```
df['y_prev'] = df['y'] - 1
df[['y', 'gdp']].set_index('y', drop=True).loc[df['y_prev']]
```

Output:

```
   gdp
y     
0  NaN
1  2.0
3  NaN
4  7.0
5  4.0
```

In order to assign these values to a new column, you need to get rid of the index (with `.values`):

```
df['gdp_lag'] = df[['y', 'gdp']].set_index('y', drop=True).loc[df['y_prev']].values
```